# Loop through months in daterange get first and last date

Tags: javascript, date

Im building a filter in node.js and i need to loop through months in a given daterange and get the first and last days of said month

every attempt i make at this after the first few months the dates start getting off

Example of results looping through 1 year

```
2019-01-01 2019-01-31
2019-02-01 2019-02-28
2019-03-01 2019-03-31
2019-03-31 2019-04-29
2019-04-30 2019-05-30
2019-05-31 2019-06-29
2019-06-30 2019-07-30
2019-07-31 2019-08-30
2019-08-31 2019-09-29
2019-09-30 2019-10-31
2019-11-01 2019-11-30
2019-12-01 2019-12-31
```

by the end it seems to get back the dates

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They go off because of day lights saving time. Just pass in the hour as well when you create the date.

```
for(let a=0;a<12;a++)
{
  let year = new Date().getFullYear()
  let firstDay = new Date(Date.UTC(year, a , 1));
  let lastDay = new Date(Date.UTC(year, a + 1, 0));
  document.body.innerHTML += `<div>${firstDay.toISOString().substring(0, 10)} - ${lastDay.toISOString().substring(0, 10)}</div>`;
}
```

[Working Example](https://codepen.io/speedofspin/pen/jOOgQMM?editors=1111)

Output

```
2019-01-01 - 2019-01-31
2019-02-01 - 2019-02-28
2019-03-01 - 2019-03-31
2019-04-01 - 2019-04-30
2019-05-01 - 2019-05-31
2019-06-01 - 2019-06-30
2019-07-01 - 2019-07-31
2019-08-01 - 2019-08-31
2019-09-01 - 2019-09-30
2019-10-01 - 2019-10-31
2019-11-01 - 2019-11-30
2019-12-01 - 2019-12-31
```

**Update

As per RobG suggestion below. Edited to remove timezone offsets altogether.

Comment: I think i love you thank you that was exactly the problem

Comment: This will fail for places with a timezone offset of 12 or greater. If using *toISOString* to format dates, you should also use UTC methods to generate the dates. Then you don't have to worry about timezone offsets, e.g. `new Date(Date.UTC(2019,0,1)).toISOString().substr(0,10)`